# Network Policy Server rule does not match users from trusted domain when in a nested group

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop-services, nps

TL;DR: Just look at the image linked below.

[User group membership diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtTVJ.png)

We have an RD Gateway and Network Policy Server, both running on Windows Server 2012 R2 in an environment with forest functional level 2008 R2. A new two-way forest trust was created with OtherCompany, and as far as I can tell the trust works fine. However, NPS is failing to allow Remote Desktop users from the trusted domain, but *only when those users are in a nested group*.

- NPS has basically one rule: Allow if user is a member of group, "Remote Users - Domain Local".
- Within this group are two other groups, "OurCompany Remote Users" (Global) and "OtherCompany Remote Users" (Domain Local).

  - Within those groups are individual user accounts from their respective domains.
- Users in "OurCompany Remote Users" have always matched the NPS rule.
- Users in "OtherCompany Remote Users" were *not* matching the rule.
- I discovered that if I added OtherCompany users *directly to the Domain Local group mentioned by the NPS rule* that they would start matching.

  - Directly adding individual users to resources is not an acceptable long-term arrangement; We need the ability to assign users to groups, and groups to have rights to resources, to avoid a security mess.

I haven't been able to find anyone else with an issue exactly like this. I would appreciate if there were some documented behavior or best practice relevant to this.